# How to make a modular website without using php?

Tags: html, web, modularity, modular

Using php, for example, would be adding this into `index.php`:

```
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

And in adding the html code in `footer.php`.

**But is it possible do the same only with html without using php or iframes?**

Comment: There are tons of ways to do it in Javascript. Possibly server-side includes. Possibly Web Components. There's no clear answer here.

Comment: An example can be an answer.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in pure html, the only way is using iframe, sorry!

Comment: But you can put all the html you want in footer.php (without php inside!) and include it, it works, but you need the .PHP

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use localStorage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

> The Web Storage API provides mechanisms by which browsers can store key/value pairs, in a much more intuitive fashion than using cookies.

an example of the idea *(obviously SO doesn't allow this in snippets 
it can be tested/copied from here https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oGorNw )*

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var loaded = localStorage.getItem("header");
  if (loaded) {// if already set, load it from visitor 
    var header = localStorage.getItem("header");
    var aside = localStorage.getItem("aside");
    var footer = localStorage.getItem("footer");
    document.getElementById("headers").innerHTML = header;
    document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = aside;
    document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = footer;
  } else {// if first visit, load and store basic content once
    var top = "<h1>hello</h1>";
    var side = '<ul><li><a href="#">link</a>';
    var bottom = "<p>My footer loaded via local storage </p>";
    localStorage.setItem("header", top);
    localStorage.setItem("aside", side);
    localStorage.setItem("footer", bottom);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: crimson;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 2px;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 2px;
  background: tomato;
}

footer,
header {
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

aside img {
  max-width: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 5vh auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="headers"></header>
<main>
  <aside id="aside"></aside>
  <section> page content</section>
</main>
<footer id="footer"></footer>
```